# Typescript не проверяет лишние свойства при передачи объекта по ссылке

Tags: typescript

```
 type Options = {
  baseURL: string
  cacheSize?: number
  tier?: 'prod' | 'dev'
 }

 class API {
  constructor(private options: Options) {}
 }

 // Ожидаемо верно
 new API({
  baseURL: 'https://api.mysite.com',
  tier: 'prod'
 })

 // Ожидаемо неверно
 new API({
  baseURL: 'https://api.mysite.com',
  badTier: 'prod'
 })
```

Почему нет ошибки в следующем фрагменте кода:

```
 let badOptions = {
  baseURL: 'https://api.mysite.com',
  badTier: 'prod'
 }

 new API(badOptions)
```

Comment: а почему должна быть ошибка? Переданный объект соответствует интерфейсу

Comment: @Grundy А почему тогда TS ругается тут: ` new API({
  baseURL: 'https://api.mysite.com',
  badTier: 'prod'
 })` - это ж тоже, по вашим словам соответствует интерфейсу, но TS делает проверку на лишние свойства. А по ссылке забывает)?

Comment: Именно так, строгая проверка соответствия полей проводится только для литералов.

Comment: Пусть останется дубликатом)

Comment: Собственно в дубликате как раз об этом.